# How to find the nearest string in a List in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

If I want to find the exact match or the next nearest for a string.
Using SQL, I can do :

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM table 
WHERE Code >= @searchcode
ORDER BY Code
```

How might I achieve this using LINQ and a List of the records.

I was expecting to be able to do something like:

```
var find = ListDS.Where(c => c.Code >= searchcode).First();
```

but you can't compare strings that way.

Note that `Code` is an alpha string, letters, numbers, symbols, whatever..

Nearest means if you have a list containing "England", "France", "Spain", and you search for "France" then you get "France". If you search for "Germany" you get "Spain".

Comment: What do you assume the `>=` operator would do on a string?

Comment: What is Code, a string or an `int`?

Comment: I'm looking for a greater than or equal comparison

Comment: Is `Code` a string containing a number?

Comment: What does "nearest" mean in the context of this string?

Comment: to compare string similar to another you have to implement the levensthein distance algorithm  http://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein do that in a string extension and you could use >= operator

Comment: No Code is an alpha string, letters, numbers, symbols, whatever ...

Comment: So nearest...  if you have a list containing "England", "France", "Spain", and you search for "France" then you get "France".  If you search for "Germany" you get "Spain".... I suppose "Find Equal or Next" would be more accurate.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qn2r1t  check the implementation    it calculates how many steps to get to the word you look for,  if you have your list , and search for france but happens to misspell it like "francr" , the value would be 1 , ie. the distance to get to "france" from "francr"

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple code  may help you

```
        List<string> ls = new List<string>();
        ls.Add("ddd");
        ls.Add("adb");
        var vv = from p in ls where p.StartsWith("a") select p;
```

select all element with starting string "a"

Answer (score 0):

If `Code` is an `int` this might work:

```
var find = ListDS.Where(c => c.Code >= searchcode).OrderBy(c => c.Code).First();
```

otherwise you need to convert it to one:

```
int code = int.Parse(searchcode);
var find = ListDS.Where(c => Convert.ToInt32(c.Code) >= code).OrderBy(c => Convert.ToInt32(c.Code)).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
class Something
{
    public string Code;
    public Something(string code)
    {
        this.Code = code;
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Something> ListDS = new List<Something>();

        ListDS.Add(new Something("test1"));
        ListDS.Add(new Something("searchword1"));
        ListDS.Add(new Something("test2"));
        ListDS.Add(new Something("searchword2"));

        string searchcode = "searchword";
        var find = ListDS.First(x => x.Code.Contains(searchcode));

        Console.WriteLine(find.Code);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

I replaced your `>=` with `.Contains`. You can also add the action into `First`, no need for `Where`.

It will not find the "nearest", just the first word containg your search parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You could compare string in C#, it will use alphabetically order:

```
var find = ListDS.Where(c => c.Code.CompareTo(searchcode) >= 0)
                 .OrderBy(c => c) // get closer one, need to order
                 .First();
```

[See the CompareTo docs.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/35f0x18w.aspx)

Note that with this method, `"10" > "2"`.